# Attempting to use invalid JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to make a test to verify that invalid JSON in a cURL request returns a 400 error code. Unfortunately, Ruby won't allow me to use invalid JSON.

```
if bad_json
  credentials = {
    "username" => username
    "password" => password
  }.to_json
else
  credentials = {
    "username" => username,
    "password" => password
  }.to_json
end
```

produces the following when I try to run the test:

```
/foo.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '}'
            "password" => password
             ^
/foo.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
            "password" => password
                         ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Is it possible to pass this invalid JSON in without the script breaking?

Comment: you miss comma. in first `if` after `"username" => username`

Comment: The syntax error you got has nothing to do with JSON. Your **Ruby** code is invalid.

Comment: @Monk_Code as stated, that is intentional.

Comment: @sawa right this code not valid.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to use the malformed JSON in my request. Based on my understanding,
    `credentials = {
      "username" => username
      "password" => password
    }.to_json`

should translate to `'{"username":username "password":password}'`, the bad request that I want.

Comment: You miss the point. You're trying to turn invalid ruby code into invalid json. Since invalid ruby code isn't valid, you can't. You need to use a media that doesn't validate syntax - like a string.

Comment: @J.Steen entering the invalid JSON as a string did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people have commented your Ruby has syntax errors. You must have valid Ruby and only makes errors in the JSON if I understand your problem correctly.

Specifically you seem to be telling Ruby to create a Hash then convert it to a String which contain texts that happens to comply with the JSON spec. Just make that text directly, then you can control how closely it conforms.

```
if bad_json
  credentials = "{\"username\":\"#{username}\" \"password\":\"#{password}\"}"
else
  credentials = "{\"username\":\"#{username}\",\"password\":\"#{password}\"}"
end
```

**EDIT** - More details

To make this point more clear here is a simplified example in irb/pry:

```
[1] pry(main)> {}.class
=> Hash
[2] pry(main)> {}.to_json
=> "{}"
[3] pry(main)> {}.to_json.class
=> String
[4] pry(main)> "{}".class
=> String
```

Here we can see that to_json simply returns a string. So if you can craft a string on your own that is conformant JSON it would be just as good as a string made a JSON processor.